# Flask SQLAlchemy: Child table with multiple parents?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm new to flask_sqlalchemy, and while I understand how the one-to-many, and many-to-many relationships work, I'm struggling to understand how I can apply them to my specific data types. I have the following three tables: TeamStat, PlayerStat, and Stat which are loosely described as follows

```
class PlayerStat(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime)
    player_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('player.player_id'), nullable=False)

class TeamStat(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime)
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team.team_id'), nullable=False)


class Stat(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    value = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
```

Since Stat is a generic table type, I would like to use it by both the PlayerStat table (for individual player stats), as well as the TeamStat table (as a sum of the stats for all players on a team). Can someone help me understand how I can refer one child table to multiple parent tables in this fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use association tables to bridge your stat table to your players and team tables. This example is pretty close to what you are already doing, except the `date` column is moved on to the stat record table and I've replaced your `PlayerStat` and `TeamStat` objects with unmapped tables.

I've assumed you have two ORM classes, `Player` and `Team` (not Flask-SQLAlchemy sorry but concept remains the same):

```py
plr_stat_assc = Table('plr_stat_assc', Base.metadata,
    Column('player_id', Integer, ForeignKey('player.id')),
    Column('stat_id', Integer, ForeignKey('stat.id'))
)

team_stat_assc = Table('team_stat_assc', Base.metadata,
    Column('team_id', Integer, ForeignKey('team.id')),
    Column('stat_id', Integer, ForeignKey('stat.id'))
)

class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    stats = relationship("Stat", secondary=plr_stat_assc)

class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'team'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    stats = relationship("Stat", secondary=team_stat_assc)

class Stat(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'stat'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.datetime)
    value = Column(String(80), nullable=False)
```

Comment: Aha! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!